# Send Get Request via PHP - without CURL

Tags: php, post

I don't have curl available on this old system (PHP4) so that can't be used, updated or added. It's not a production machine, just used for internal use.

In my browser I can enter the following:

http://192.168.0.1/device?action=COMMAND

and the device at 192.168.0.1 will action the COMMAND sent to it.
This is fine and works. Access to this device is restricted to a set of specific IP Addresses.

I'd like to be able to call that URL from a PHP script. My PHP server is in the approved list, so that won't be an issue.

I've tried file_get_contents and fread but neither have worked.

Anyone any ideas I could try ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can go with using this:

```
http_get('http://192.168.0.1/device', $ArrayOfParameters);
```

However you could take look at `sockets` or you could have a look at `Pecl_Http`

[**Pecl_Http**](https://pecl.php.net/)

[**Sockets**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php)

**You shouldn't be using `PHP 4`. It is discontinued and so doesn't receive any security patches.** - [**PHP 4 Discountinued**](https://secure.php.net/releases/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This box doesn't have http_get support so I'm stuck again.

Comment: @JeffVader - You shouldn't be using PHP 4. Has my answer says, it's discontinued

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
function GetRequest($URL){

    $get = @file_get_contents($URL);

    if($get === FALSE)
        return 0;

    return $get;

}
```

use:

`$result = GetRequest("http://localhost/test.php?foo=bar");`

also check what ip your server is running on if your ip is restricted.

Comment: Thanks - I've done that and echo'd $result which returns 0
No errors are shown, but nothing appears to happen.

If I run the same URL in my browser as used in the GetRequest, it works.

What I need to do is send a GET request to the IP Address, the user I need to use is :

http://192.168.0.1/device?action=COMMAND

The device on 192.168.0.1 should then action the command I would see that in the logs.

Comment: The file isn't being found, have you tried just doing  `$result = GetRequest("http://192.168.0.1/");` if you `print_r($result);` after and get 0 then its because your server is getting rejected from 192.168.0.1

Comment: it's in the ACL. I've removed all other entries and it now fails from my Browser, so I know the setting have updated.

I've added only that IP address and I still get 0

is it because I'm using :

http://192.168.0.1/device?action=COMMAND

and Not :

http://192.168.0.1/device.php?action=COMMAND

Comment: if its getting 0 its because the request is rejected regardless of the url, like i said try `$result = GetRequest("http://192.168.0.1/"); print_r($result);` and tell me the result, if its 0 the problem is the server with your script on being rejected...